# n-th order polynomial written as a function of its roots

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots

I was looking at an eigenvalue problem, where it was stated that for a $n \times n$ matrix $A$, the characteristic polynomial can be written has

$$
\det(A - \lambda I) = p(\lambda) = (-1)^n(\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2)\ldots (\lambda - \lambda_n)
$$

where $\lambda_i$ are roots of the polynomial.

Is this true in general for any type of n-th order polynomial? Where did the $(-1)^n$ come from?

Comment: Cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Formal_definition)

Answer (score 1):

The [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Corollaries) implies that any polynomial $p(\lambda)$ of degree $n$ can be written as
$$ p(\lambda) = c \prod_{j=1}^n (\lambda - \lambda_j)$$
where the $\lambda_j$ are the roots of $p$, listed with multiplicities, and $c$ is constant.  Those roots are the eigenvalues.  The constant here is $(-1)^n$ because for $\lambda = 0$ we have $$p(0) = \det(A) = \prod_{j=1}^n \lambda^j = (-1)^n \prod_{j=1}^n (-\lambda_j)$$

Comment: I'm a confused on the constant $c$. Why does the fundamental theorem of algebra implies this factor is included, and why is it a constant?

Comment: @David:  you could multiply a polynomial by any constant without changing the roots

Comment: Right, I agree, but I we're just talking about reproducing the original polynomial from the factored form, why is the $c$ needed?